# How do you make a t4 template installable in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, t4

I have written a couple of t4 templates for EF4, I want to get other developers to use them, so id like to make them installable in VS so that people cna jsut add them to their projects.

I have no idea how to do this. Any idea about where i should start reading? Idid a quick google and had no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to create a VS item template.

There is an export template wizard accessed vie the File/ExportTemplate menu.
After you've exported a T4 template, you'll probably want to manually edit the resultign item, as it doesn't handle the generated file well by default.

You'll have your template from the wizard as a zip file.
Unzip this and remove the generated file.
Then edit the Foo.vstemplate file and remove the line referencing the generated file.
Finally zip the files up again.

Your colleagues can just drop this zip file into their user templates directory:
C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates

Comment: ahh cool, that sounds like the ticket ;) Will try it out tommorow

Answer (score 0):

For external sharing, your best bet is probably to create a nuget package.

Have a look at this link:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/12/uploading-packages-to-the-nuget-gallery.aspx

Comment: good idea, unfortunatley i will not be able to release this publically. When i said other developers i meant collegues internally.  It is also pretty specific so i am not sure about its reuse value.

Comment: It is possible I believe to have an internal nuget repository. However, it's probably not a proportional effort.